# radgrid data disappear after filtering

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I am using a RadGrid to show some data and I have set AllowFilteringByColumn to true, but when I try to filter rows, a postback occurs and my RadGrid content disappears (all the things disappear and just a border remains).

```
<telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="pnlShowGrid" runat="server" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel4">                   
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server"
            CssClass="RadGrid" Height="400px"
            ClientSettings-Selecting-AllowRowSelect="true"
            AllowPaging="True" PageSize="20" AllowSorting="True"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowAutomaticUpdates="True"
            ShowStatusBar="True" AllowAutomaticDeletes="True"
            AllowFilteringByColumn="True"
            Width="100%"
            OnUpdateCommand="RadGrid1_UpdateCommand"
            OnItemDeleted="rgrd_Edit_ItemDeleted"
            OnItemCommand="RadGrid1_ItemCommand">

            <ExportSettings ExportOnlyData="True">
                <Pdf DefaultFontFamily="Arial Unicode MS" FontType="Embed" />
                <Excel AutoFitImages="True" />
            </ExportSettings>
            <FilterMenu EnableImageSprites="true">
            </FilterMenu>
            <ExportSettings ExportOnlyData="true" OpenInNewWindow="true">
                <Excel Format="ExcelML"></Excel>
                <Excel AutoFitImages="true" />
                <Pdf FontType="Embed" AllowPrinting="true" />
                <Pdf DefaultFontFamily="Arial Unicode MS" />
            </ExportSettings>
            <ClientSettings AllowGroupExpandCollapse="True" Selecting-AllowRowSelect="true">
                <Selecting AllowRowSelect="True" />
            </ClientSettings>
            <MasterTableView
                CommandItemDisplay="TopAndBottom" Dir="RTL" AllowFilteringByColumn="true"
                DataKeyNames="AccessPesrmission_ID"
                NoDetailRecordsText="??? ?????? ???? ????? !"
                NoMasterRecordsText="??? ?????? ???? ????? !">
            <CommandItemSettings ExportToPdfText="Export to PDF" AddNewRecordText="????? ????? ????" ShowAddNewRecordButton="false" RefreshText="?????????" ShowExportToExcelButton="true" ShowExportToWordButton="true" ShowExportToPdfButton="false">
            </CommandItemSettings>
                <RowIndicatorColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter RowIndicator column" FilterControlWidth="20%"></RowIndicatorColumn>
            <ExpandCollapseColumn Visible="True" FilterControlAltText="Filter ExpandColumn column" FilterControlWidth="20%"></ExpandCollapseColumn>
                <Columns>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn Display="false" FilterControlWidth="10px" DataField="AccessPesrmission_ID" DataType="System.Int32" FilterControlAltText="Filter AccessPesrmission_ID column" HeaderText="?????" SortExpression="AccessPesrmission_ID" UniqueName="AccessPesrmission_ID" AndCurrentFilterFunction="Contains" AutoPostBackOnFilter="True" CurrentFilterFunction="Contains">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn DataField="AccessPermission_Read" DataType="System.Boolean" FilterControlAltText="Filter AccessPermission_Read column" HeaderText="?????" SortExpression="AccessPermission_Read" UniqueName="AccessPermission_Read" AndCurrentFilterFunction="Contains" AutoPostBackOnFilter="True" CurrentFilterFunction="Contains">
                    </telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn>
                    <telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn DataField="AccessPermission_Add" DataType="System.Boolean" FilterControlAltText="Filter AccessPermission_Add column" HeaderText="???" SortExpression="AccessPermission_Add" UniqueName="AccessPermission_Add">
                    </telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn>
                    <telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn DataField="AccessPermission_Edit" DataType="System.Boolean" FilterControlAltText="Filter AccessPermission_Edit column" HeaderText="??????" SortExpression="AccessPermission_Edit" UniqueName="AccessPermission_Edit">
                    </telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn>
                    <telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn DataField="AccessPermission_Delete" DataType="System.Boolean" FilterControlAltText="Filter AccessPermission_Delete column" HeaderText="???" SortExpression="AccessPermission_Delete" UniqueName="AccessPermission_Delete">
                    </telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn Display="false" FilterControlWidth="10px" DataField="AccessPesrmission_SatheSazmani_ID" FilterControlAltText="Filter AccessPesrmission_SatheSazmani_ID column" HeaderText="????? ??? ???????" SortExpression="AccessPesrmission_SatheSazmani_ID" UniqueName="AccessPesrmission_SatheSazmani_ID" AndCurrentFilterFunction="Contains" AutoPostBackOnFilter="True" CurrentFilterFunction="Contains">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn FilterControlWidth="40px" DataField="VahedSazmani_FarsiName" FilterControlAltText="Filter VahedSazmani_FarsiName column" HeaderText="???? ???????" SortExpression="VahedSazmani_FarsiName" UniqueName="VahedSazmani_FarsiName">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn FilterControlWidth="40px" DataField="Semat_Name" FilterControlAltText="Filter Semat_Name column" HeaderText="???" SortExpression="Semat_Name" UniqueName="Semat_Name">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn FilterControlWidth="40px" DataField="GrooheKarmandi_NameFarsi" FilterControlAltText="Filter GrooheKarmandi_NameFarsi column" HeaderText="???? ???????" SortExpression="GrooheKarmandi_NameFarsi" UniqueName="GrooheKarmandi_NameFarsi">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn FilterControlWidth="40px" DataField="Personel_NameKamel" FilterControlAltText="Filter Personel_NameKamel column" HeaderText="?????" SortExpression="Personel_NameKamel" UniqueName="Personel_NameKamel">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn FilterControlWidth="40px" DataField="COM_Name" FilterControlAltText="Filter COM_Name column" HeaderText="????" SortExpression="COM_Name" UniqueName="COM_Name">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn FilterControlWidth="70px" DataField="Source_Desc" FilterControlAltText="Filter Source_Desc column" HeaderText="????" SortExpression="Source_Desc" UniqueName="Source_Desc">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn FilterControlWidth="20px" DataField="SourceType_Desc" FilterControlAltText="Filter SourceType_Desc column" HeaderText="??? ????" SortExpression="SourceType_Desc" UniqueName="SourceType_Desc">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridButtonColumn CommandName="Delete" ButtonType="ImageButton" Text="???"
                        UniqueName="columnDelete" ConfirmText="??? ?? ?????? ????? ???? ??? ?? ??? ???? ?"
                        ConfirmDialogType="RadWindow" ImageUrl="../../assets/img/icon/del-layer.png"
                        ConfirmDialogHeight="180" ConfirmDialogWidth="380" FooterStyle-Width="60px"
                        HeaderStyle-Width="60px" ItemStyle-Width="60px">
                    </telerik:GridButtonColumn>
                    <telerik:GridButtonColumn CommandName="Edit" AndCurrentFilterFunction="Contains"
                        ButtonType="ImageButton" ImageUrl="../../assets/img/icon/edit.png"
                        AutoPostBackOnFilter="True" CurrentFilterFunction="Contains" Text="??????"
                        FooterStyle-Width="60px" HeaderStyle-Width="60px" ItemStyle-Width="60px"
                        UniqueName="columnEdit">
                    </telerik:GridButtonColumn>                                   
                </Columns>

                <EditFormSettings InsertCaption="????? ????? ????" CaptionFormatString="?????? ???? ?? ?? : {0}"
                    CaptionDataField="COM_ID" EditFormType="Template" PopUpSettings-Modal="true" FormTableStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" FormCaptionStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" PopUpSettings-CloseButtonToolTip="????" UserControlName="popupform" PopUpSettings-Width="800">
                    <EditColumn UniqueName="EditCommandColumn1" FilterControlAltText="Filter EditCommandColumn1 column"></EditColumn>
                    <FormTableStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></FormTableStyle>
                    <FormCaptionStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></FormCaptionStyle>
                    <FormTemplate>
                    </FormTemplate>
                    <PopUpSettings Modal="True" Width="800px" CloseButtonToolTip="????"></PopUpSettings>
                </EditFormSettings>

                <PagerStyle PageSizeControlType="RadComboBox"></PagerStyle>
            </MasterTableView>
            <PagerStyle PageSizeControlType="RadComboBox" />
        </telerik:RadGrid>
    </div>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource_Grid" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PigisConnectionString %>">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlCompany" Name="COM_ID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlVahedSazmani" Name="VahedSazmani_ID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
</telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
```

I load data to the RadGrid with the below function. (I call the function in page load)

```
void LoadData()
{
    SqlDataSource_Grid.SelectParameters.Clear();
    SqlDataSource_Grid.SelectCommand = "spSCT_Select_From_SCT_AccessPermission";

    SqlDataSource_Grid.DataBind();
    RadGrid1.DataSource = SqlDataSource_Grid;
    RadGrid1.Rebind();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please add NeedDatasource event in your radgrid.

```
<telerik:RadGrid runat="server" ID="RadGrid1" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource">
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

Your C# code:

```
protected void RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{   
    SqlDataSource_Grid.SelectParameters.Clear();
    SqlDataSource_Grid.SelectCommand = "spSCT_Select_From_SCT_AccessPermission";

    SqlDataSource_Grid.DataBind();
    RadGrid1.DataSource = SqlDataSource_Grid;
}
```

It will automatically rebind/databind your radgrid whenever its needed. please check below link for more information.
[Commands that invoke Rebind() implicitly](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-commands-that-invoke-rebind-implicitly.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the RadGrid1_NeedDataSource method where you tell your grid what his datasource should be AND also make sure that you call a Radgrid1.Rebind() at the end of your action method